# How to determine model array index in editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My view model contains a list of Items, like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   public string Question { get; set; }
   public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

My view employs an editor template to render all of the Items.

```
@model MyApp.Models.MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @* Display all of the questions and answers *@
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
}
```

and the Item.cshtml editor template renders each question and an editor for its associated answer:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Item
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Answer)
```

In the rendered HTML, the EditorFor magic generates element names that include array notation that map to my model hierarchy, e.g.:

```
<input name="Items[0].Answer"
```

**My question is:** I want to render a `<div>` element whose id contains the same array index value in brackets, like this:

```
<div id="Items[0].something">
  <something />
</div>
```

Is there an easy way for Item.cshtml to fabricate the id value, including the correct bracket notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use NameFor extension in MVC 4:

```
<div id="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Comment)">
```

Comment: Please see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004928/use-html-namefor-within-a-foreach-indexer).

Comment: This was helpful! For use with id's, `Html.IdFor` might be a better choice though.

Comment: I tried Html.IdFor and it produced "Items[0].something". gutted. I was hoping for the Index number 0

Answer (score 2):

While I was going through the exercise of writing the question, I figured out the answer. As long as I've spent 20 minutes writing the question, I figure I might as well share the answer in case someone else wants to do the same thing.

To fabricate a name that contains a prefix that maps to the view model:

```
<div id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("something")">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Comment)
</div>
```