# Element naming convention in Razor generator within a foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to generate element names using `Html.NameFor<>` method, here's my code:

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
  <input type="hidden" name="@Html.NameFor(m=> category.CategoryId)" 
    value="@category.CategoryId" />
}
```

The generated item's `name` get this value: `category.CategoryId`, instead of `Categories[i].CategoryId` (where `i` refers to the current indexer).

Why isn't it working?

Comment: hmm, it must not recognize its being accessed within a loop

Comment: So how does the default element generator work within loops? Does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in short, use a for loop instead of a foreach loop (see the answer here). You need to manually index it

[MVC Razor view nested foreach's model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894442/mvc-razor-view-nested-foreachs-model)

EDIT: added sample code

```
@for(int i=0; i < Model.ListTwo.Count; i++) 
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.ListTwo[i].Id)
}
```

Okay, for collections that inherit from ICollection, try

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CollectionThree.Count; i++) 
{
   @Html.Hidden("CollectionThree[" + i + "].Id", Model.CollectionThree.ElementAt(i).Id)
}
```

Another edit:
To avoid using the property name, you could do something like

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CollectionThree.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.Hidden(Html.NameFor(t => Model.CollectionThree) + "[" + i + "]." +
                Html.NameFor(t =>Model.CollectionThree.ElementAt(i).Id)
               ,Model.CollectionThree.ElementAt(i).Id )
}
```

Its inelegant, but it doesn't hardcode the property name.

And then lets take those guys out of the loop

```
 @{
   var collectionname = Html.NameFor(t => Model.CollectionThree);
   var propname = Html.NameFor(t => Model.CollectionThree.First().Id);
  }

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CollectionThree.Count; i++)
 {
      @Html.Hidden( collectionname+ "[" + i + "]." + propname ,Model.CollectionThree.ElementAt(i).Id )
 }
```

My apologies for not responding earlier. I logged out as I had other things to do. You also may want to do a null check ie, if count > 0, then assign the propname, otherwise skip the whole thing

Comment: In my scenario, index accessors are invalid, the `Categories` property is of `ICollection<Category>`, that doesn't support an indexer. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Actually my solution is missing the property name, any assistant will be appreciated. Even splitting it up in few fields, but no hard-coding property names.

Answer (score 1):

According to [user1778606's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004967/75500), I will use the prop. name and indexer separately, like this:

```
@{
 var modelName = Html.NameFor(m => m.Categories);
 var catIndex = 0;   
}

@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{ 
 <input type="hidden" class="checkbox"
   name="@string.Format("{0}[{1}]", modelName, catIndex++)"
   value="@category.CategoryId" />      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.HiddenFor` and pass in the array indexed expression for `CategoryId`

```
@for(int i=0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Categories[i].CategoryId)
}
```